# How can I create view in SQL without duplicate entries?

Tags: php, sql

**First I have Table SUM_REPANDMAINT,
Table`s Column name:**

ACTUAL_COST,
PROJECTED_COST,
TOTAL_PREV,
TOTAL_PRESENT,
VARIANCE,
VARIANCE_PER,
LIMIT,
COST_CENTER,
ID,
PLANT,
BUDGET_YEAR,
VERSION,

**Second I have View V_SUM_REPANDMAINT,
View`s Column name:**

USERNAME,
CHARGE_CC,
BUDGET_YEAR,
VERSION,
PLANT,
CHARGE_CC,
PART_DESC,
YEAR_DATE_USD,

This images may help understand the issue:

[image]

[image]

I need to get non repeating values.

Note: The sum of YEAR_DATE_USD is based on PLANT AND CHARGE_CC

My Query:

```
SELECT 
   A.ACTUAL_COST,
   A.PROJECTED_COST,
   A.TOTAL_PREV,
   A.TOTAL_PRESENT,
   A.VARIANCE,
   A.VARIANCE_PER,
   A."LIMIT",
   A.COST_CENTER,
   A.PLANT,
   A.BUDGET_YEAR,
   A."VERSION",
   B.BUDGET_YEAR,
   B."VERSION",
   B.PLANT,
   B.CHARGE_CC,
   B.PART_DESC,
   B.YEAR_DATE_USD
FROM
   CMS.SUM_REPANDMAINT A,
   CMS.V_SUM_REPANDMAINT B

WHERE 
   (A.BUDGET_YEAR = B.BUDGET_YEAR(+)) AND 
   (A."VERSION" = B."VERSION"(+)) AND 
   (A.PLANT = B.PLANT(+)) AND 
   (A.COST_CENTER = B.CHARGE_CC(+)) AND
   (B.USERNAME = '[usr_name]')
```

Comment: use group by for your unique columns

Answer (score 3):

Try using `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` on your unique columns. This will group some results.

Documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I already added DISTINCT to column name A.TOTAL_PRESENT and it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicates it means that :

- either you are not joining on all the required columns (need to add a statement to the WHERE clause for these columns)
- or it is normal for you to have multiple rows, in that    case you
  need to aggregate them using a GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, It is normal for me to have multiple rows. How can I group by the field A.TOTAL_PRESENT?

Comment: It depends on how you want to group them. You need to explicit the way you want to merge the values of the duplicates (do you keep the first one, do you sum them, do you take the average etc...).I advise you to take a moment to look up how GROUP BY works. Basically you list the columns on which to group (when values are equal) in the GROUP BY clause, and you use aggregation functions (SUM, FIRST etc...) in the SELECT clause. Here is a link that may help you : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp